# JavaScript drawImage() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, draw, game-engine

I'm trying to code some simple game and I'm stuck at drawing an assets on the canvas. I have made an AssetsLoader "class" that loads images and save them as image objects. For the start I just wanted to draw some of the loaded assets. But drawImage function doesn't show anything....I know that my image is loaded by writing object on consol which gives me this output: `<img name="player" src="../assets/images/player.png">`

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if(!context){
      alert('Upgrade browser');
  }else{
      startGame();
  }

  function startGame(){
      AssetsLoader.getAllAssets();
      console.log(AssetsLoader.images.player); // image is loaded
      context.drawImage(AssetsLoader.images.player, 0, 0); // doesn't work
  }
```

EDIT:
ok my bad, I put '../' in front of the image path because my project structure look like this:

```
assets
    images
       player.png
js
    script for AssetsLoader
```

and I thought I have to go down one level to access image.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just fixed this on my canvas. The fixed code would be:

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img1 = new Image();
  img1.src = "../assets/images/player.png";

  context.drawImage(img1,100,100);
```

The reason why you make the img1 var is because that adds the img element to the canvas. Then with img1.src you set the source of the image. When I do drawImage(), first, I insert img1 which includes the source of the image. The second parameter is the X position and the third parameter is the Y position.

Comment: I think Siam's answer makes the canvas drawImage() function soooo much more complicated then it has to be.